# Create a fault in assembly instructions with as few bytes as possible

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, fault

I'm trying to induce a fault in a running process at specific assembly instructions. I am able to change the instructions, but am unsure how to reliably create a fault.

I want to make sure that the other instructions are left unchanged and the process only crashes when the specific instruction is executed. So what I'd need is to create fault with 1 or 2 bytes of assembly if possible. If the original instructions is larger I can pad it with NOPs.

For example: How can I change these 2 bytes, so that it will crash when executed.

```
7f a9      | jg
```

I thought about setting the opcode to an arbitrary value, but I'm not certain that this will actually work.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!
Thanks, Pedro!

Comment: What architecture is this?  For x86, try `HLT`, `0xf4`.  It's a privileged instruction and will cause a GPF when executed by unprivileged code.

Comment: 0xcc just takes one byte.

Comment: You don't need to pad with NOP.  If you replace the first byte with a faulting insn, it will fault.  It doesn't matter if the bytes after it decode to nonsense, because they won't be executed at all (or if you're writing a debugger, until after you put back the original byte and return from SIGILL or SIGTRAP.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest way in most cases is using

```
CCh    int 3
```

as a one byte opcode triggering a debugging exception.

If you're looking for another simple, debugging-resistant way of crashing an user-application, you could always use privileged instructions which are only valid in CPL0 aka kernel mode, e.g.

```
0f 08  invd  (invalidate internal caches)
   f4  hlt   (enter Halt state)
0f 0b  ud2   (invalid opcode)
```

Also pretty effective under most circumstances and also working in CPL0 is jumping to some random address with two one-byte opcodes like

```
50     push eax
c3     ret
```

There are certainly other possibilities. Simply because it is easier to crash a program than keep it running :)

EDIT: included `HLT`, `UD2` due to suggestion in comments. `CLI` and `STI` would not #GP in every scenario, e.g. IOPL=CPL=3.

Comment: Note on a Unix system, `INT3` will usually produce `SIGTRAP` instead of `SIGSEGV`, which may or may not be what's wanted.

Comment: `cli`/`sti`/`hlt` are single byte, also instead of random address use a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @Jester: Yes, I thought about including CLI. Concerning the NULL-ptr: I tried encoding a NULL-ptr-memory access with two bytes, but failed. Any suggestions?

Comment: If two bytes is ok, then UD2 will trigger an illegal-insn exception.  (Which will get Linux to deliver a `SIGILL`).  The OP just says fault everywhere except tags, so IDK what he wants.

Comment: @zx485: That's an interesting question, to try to access NULL in two bytes.  Three is pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Regarding the type of fault: I only need to ensure that the OS will terminate execution of the process. Which signal is not important.

Comment: Just a note: CLI, HLT and STI are indeed valid at CPL=3. They just need CPL<=IOPL. If you do a iopl(3); before executing CLI, it will do it just fine. Try iopl(3); then CLI then HLT and you will freeze the whole machine (iopl only available to root, of course).

Comment: You could also just through a `RET` in somewhere... or perhaps worse, an `IRET`.  You will corrupt the stack frame.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: as an anecdote, Windows 9x's DOS box ran at IOPL 3.